# Empty relative div with a fixed size?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div with `position:relative;` that is empty, however it is filled with a javascript rendered image. Currently, even though I have set a width and height of 10% and 20% respectively, the div has no height or width unless I actually put some html inside. I would like to avoid putting absolute pixel dimensions though, because of different screen sizes. How can this be solved?

Edit: the div in question

```
<div id="protovis">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body 
{
  width:100%; height:100%;
  margin:0;
  ...
}

#protovis
{
  margin-left:10%;
  width:80%; height:25%;
  position:relative;
}
```

Comment: what is the wrapper for this div? can you post the html of the relevant elements?

Comment: There isn't very much code to speak of, just an empty div. Ive posted it in an edit above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use percentage-based dimensions, the parent element must have dimensions. These dimensions on the parent can also be percentages, but the parent's parent must then have some dimensions.

Check it out here: http://jsfiddle.net/NWWY8/

Comment: so I must use a px width somewhere then? Is there some manner of avoiding issues with different screen sizes with this approach?

Comment: No, every parent can have a percentage dimension as well, all the way out to your body tag.

Comment: The div is directly inside the body tag, which has a height and width 100%. yet it still isn't showing up.. I have posted the css above.

Comment: Change that CSS rule to `html, body { width:100%; height: 100%;}`

Comment: Hmm, now the div has a height and width, the width is correct, but the height seems to be arbitrary. 1092x20px according to the console, which is more like 5% than 25%, although the 'computed height' says 25%.

Comment: Any other CSS on the page?  I don't know what else to tell you - this is CSS, this is how it works.  If something isn't happening as expected, there's a factor at play here that isn't being accounted for.

Comment: No, nothing else. Perhaps there is something to do with the javascript graphics library. I do see that it is setting display to inline-block, even though I haven't done so myself. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: I figured it out. What you said was correct, I was just missing the comma in between html and body. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the parent element(s) are set to size to their contents.